# Android Tasker App Advance Input Shell command

Tags: android, shell

I have this shell command in android `input tap 653 100` using Tasker app to simulate a tap command. This one is working but how do i execute the command for say 50 times or 100 times? I know I can add more task in Tasker App but Thats a lot of work. So if you know anything or any command that i can input like for example `input tap 653 100 -100`  or  `input tap 653 100 -50` which is -100 and -50 are for how many times a command should execute or how do i loop and execute a task in `Tasker app`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for q in `seq 1 50`; do input tap 653 100 ; done
```

Should do the trick...